# Create image from tableView section

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

Does anyone know of a way to render a tableView section (header + cells) as an Image. My last resort would be to grab the header and each cell individually and render them but i'd like to avoid that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UITableView cells and headers are built to be reusable. It means that if all your cells which you want to render as a part of an image do not fit on the screen then you should preload them and draw manually.

Comment: I understand that...but that is not really a problem..the entire sections fits on screen and i can scroll to it before to make sure it gets rendered

Comment: If you are hundred percent sure that everything will be on the screen, then you can create screenshot of entire table view and crop it.